# Can you use COUNT DISTINCT with an OVER clause?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to improve the performance of the following query:

```
        UPDATE  [#TempTable]
        SET     Received = r.Number
        FROM    [#TempTable] 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT  AgentID,
                            RuleID,
                            COUNT(DISTINCT (GroupId)) Number
                    FROM    [#TempTable]
                    WHERE   Passed = 1
                    GROUP BY AgentID,
                            RuleID
                   ) r ON r.RuleID = [#TempTable].RuleID AND
                          r.AgentID = [#TempTable].AgentID
```

Currently with my test data it takes about a minute.  I have a limited amount of input into changes on the over all stored procedure where this query resides but I can probably get them to modify this one query.  Or add an index.  I tried adding the following index:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_test ON #TempTable(AgentID, RuleId, GroupId, Passed)
```

And it actually doubled the amount of time the query takes.  I get the same effect with a NON-CLUSTERED index.

I tried re-writing it as follows with no effect.

```
        WITH r AS (SELECT  AgentID,
                            RuleID,
                            COUNT(DISTINCT (GroupId)) Number
                    FROM    [#TempTable]
                    WHERE   Passed = 1
                    GROUP BY AgentID,
                            RuleID
            ) 
        UPDATE  [#TempTable]
        SET     Received = r.Number
        FROM    [#TempTable] 
        INNER JOIN r 
            ON r.RuleID = [#TempTable].RuleID AND
               r.AgentID = [#TempTable].AgentID
```

Next I tried to use a windowing function like this.

```
        UPDATE  [#TempTable]
        SET     Received = COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN Passed=1 THEN GroupId ELSE NULL END)) 
                    OVER (PARTITION BY AgentId, RuleId)
        FROM    [#TempTable]
```

At this point I started to get the error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'distinct'.
```

So I have two questions.  First can you not do a COUNT DISTINCT with the OVER clause or did I just write it incorrectly? And second can anyone suggest an improvement I haven't already tried? FYI this is a SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise instance.

EDIT: Here is a link to the original execution plan.  I should also note that my big problem is that this query is being run 30-50 times.

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4C359AF42063BD98%21772

EDIT2: Here is the full loop that the statement is in as requested in the comments.  I'm checking with the person who works with this on a regular basis as to the purpose of the loop.

```
DECLARE @Counting INT              
SELECT  @Counting = 1              

--  BEGIN:  Cascading Rule check --           
WHILE @Counting <= 30              
    BEGIN      

        UPDATE  w1
        SET     Passed = 1
        FROM    [#TempTable] w1,
                [#TempTable] w3
        WHERE   w3.AgentID = w1.AgentID AND
                w3.RuleID = w1.CascadeRuleID AND
                w3.RulePassed = 1 AND
                w1.Passed = 0 AND
                w1.NotFlag = 0      

        UPDATE  w1
        SET     Passed = 1
        FROM    [#TempTable] w1,
                [#TempTable] w3
        WHERE   w3.AgentID = w1.AgentID AND
                w3.RuleID = w1.CascadeRuleID AND
                w3.RulePassed = 0 AND
                w1.Passed = 0 AND
                w1.NotFlag = 1        

        UPDATE  [#TempTable]
        SET     Received = r.Number
        FROM    [#TempTable] 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT  AgentID,
                            RuleID,
                            COUNT(DISTINCT (GroupID)) Number
                    FROM    [#TempTable]
                    WHERE   Passed = 1
                    GROUP BY AgentID,
                            RuleID
                   ) r ON r.RuleID = [#TempTable].RuleID AND
                          r.AgentID = [#TempTable].AgentID                            

        UPDATE  [#TempTable]
        SET     RulePassed = 1
        WHERE   TotalNeeded = Received              

        SELECT  @Counting = @Counting + 1              
    END
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This construction is not currently supported in SQL Server. It could (and should, in my opinion) be implemented in a future version.

Applying one of the workarounds listed in the [feedback item](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32890510-over-clause-enhancement-request-distinct-clause) reporting this deficiency, your query could be rewritten as:

```
WITH UpdateSet AS
(
    SELECT 
        AgentID, 
        RuleID, 
        Received, 
        Calc = SUM(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (
            PARTITION BY AgentID, RuleID) 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT  
            AgentID,
            RuleID,
            Received,
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY AgentID, RuleID, GroupID 
                ORDER BY GroupID)
        FROM    #TempTable
        WHERE   Passed = 1
    ) AS X
)
UPDATE UpdateSet
SET Received = Calc;
```

The resulting execution plan is:

[image: Plan]

This has the advantage of avoiding an Eager Table Spool for [Halloween Protection](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/02/t-sql-queries/halloween-problem-part-2) (due to the self-join), but it introduces a sort (for the window) and an often-inefficient Lazy Table Spool construction to calculate and apply the `SUM OVER (PARTITION BY)` result to all rows in the window. How it performs in practice is an exercise only you can perform.

The overall approach is a difficult one to make perform well. Applying updates (especially ones based on a self-join) recursively to a large structure may be good for debugging but it is a recipe for poor performance. Repeated large scans, memory spills, and Halloween issues are just some of the issues. Indexing and (more) temporary tables can help, but very careful analysis is needed especially if the index is updated by other statements in the process (maintaining indexes affects query plan choices and adds I/O).

Ultimately, solving the underlying problem would make for interesting consultancy work, but it is too much for this site. I hope this answer addresses the surface question though.

---

Alternative interpretation of the original query (results in updating more rows):

```
WITH UpdateSet AS
(
    SELECT 
        AgentID, 
        RuleID, 
        Received, 
        Calc = SUM(CASE WHEN Passed = 1 AND rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (
            PARTITION BY AgentID, RuleID) 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT  
            AgentID,
            RuleID,
            Received,
            Passed,
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY AgentID, RuleID, Passed, GroupID
                ORDER BY GroupID)
        FROM    #TempTable
    ) AS X
)
UPDATE UpdateSet
SET Received = Calc
WHERE Calc > 0;
```

[image: Plan 2]

Note: eliminating the sort (e.g. by providing an index) might reintroduce the need for an Eager Spool or something else to provide the necessary Halloween Protection. Sort is a blocking operator, so it provides full phase separation.

Answer (score 7):

Necromancing:

It's relativiely simple to emulate a count distinct over partition by with DENSE_RANK:

```
;WITH baseTable AS
(
              SELECT 'RM1' AS RM, 'ADR1' AS ADR
    UNION ALL SELECT 'RM1' AS RM, 'ADR1' AS ADR
    UNION ALL SELECT 'RM2' AS RM, 'ADR1' AS ADR
    UNION ALL SELECT 'RM2' AS RM, 'ADR2' AS ADR
    UNION ALL SELECT 'RM2' AS RM, 'ADR2' AS ADR
    UNION ALL SELECT 'RM2' AS RM, 'ADR3' AS ADR
    UNION ALL SELECT 'RM3' AS RM, 'ADR1' AS ADR
    UNION ALL SELECT 'RM2' AS RM, 'ADR1' AS ADR
    UNION ALL SELECT 'RM3' AS RM, 'ADR1' AS ADR
    UNION ALL SELECT 'RM3' AS RM, 'ADR2' AS ADR
)
,CTE AS
(
    SELECT RM, ADR, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY RM ORDER BY ADR) AS dr 
    FROM baseTable 
    -- Caveat: If there are NULL-values, add "WHERE ADR IS NOT NULL" here
)
SELECT
     RM
    ,ADR
    
    ,COUNT(CTE.ADR) OVER (PARTITION BY CTE.RM ORDER BY ADR) AS cnt1 
    ,COUNT(CTE.ADR) OVER (PARTITION BY CTE.RM) AS cnt2 
    -- Geht nicht / Doesn't work 
    --,COUNT(DISTINCT CTE.ADR) OVER (PARTITION BY CTE.RM ORDER BY CTE.ADR) AS cntDist
    ,MAX(CTE.dr) OVER (PARTITION BY CTE.RM ORDER BY CTE.RM) AS cntDistEmu 
FROM CTE
```

**Edit:**
Caveat: Obviously you need to add WHERE ADR IS NOT NULL if there are null-values.

Comment: The semantics of this are not the same as `count` if the column is nullable. If it contains any nulls you need to subtract 1.